# Ubuntu 12.04 media player does not show video?

Tags: 12.04, video, media

This question seems poor but i really facing this problem (I am new to ubuntu).
I install Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP laptop.
I also upgraded all its packages using sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.
But when I play any video file through media player (default and smplayer), i can only hear audio but no video is seen, screen becomes blanks. All types of video file can be played but only audio can be heard, no video.

Comment: Do you have a graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a codec problem.

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Also, you should try a better video player. I recommend VLC.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Have fun!